# Vector Template Class: erase(iterator begin, iterator end)

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, vector, iterator

So I am trying to implement a vector template class and I am trying to write an erase function. The erase function takes two iterators, `start` and `end`. It then erases every element from position `start` to `end` including `start`, but not `end`. After it erases the range of elements it shifts the elements left so that there are no empty elements in the middle of the array (I can try and explain better if this is not clear enough).

The private member data for the class is an integer called `Size`, which stores the current number of elements in the array, an integer called `Capacity` which stores the current space allocated for the array, and an array called `Arr`. I'm not great with iterators yet, can someone explain to me how I can do this better or how to fix it?

```
template <typename T>
typename Vector<T>::iterator Vector<T>::erase(iterator start, iterator end)
{
    iterator x = start;

    for(; x != end; x++)
    {
        Arr[x].~T();
    }

    for(iterator x = start; x < theSize - (start - end); x++)
    {
        Arr[x] = Arr[x + (start - end)]; 
    }

    Size -= end - start;      

}
```

Comment: *can someone explain to me how I can do this better* -- Use `std::vector`.  It works already.  And what is this about? `Arr[x].~T();` ?

Comment: Also, std::vector::erase() would just move the elements to erase to the end of the vector, and just change the `size` entry.  Nothing is actually deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot destroy objects in the middle of the vector, and then assign to them. You can only assign to "live" objects.

What you could do is (move)assign members from `[end-iterator, vector::end())` over the `start` and following element. And *then* destroy excess objecs at the end of the vector.

Here is an example using the real `std::vector` interface with `const_iterator` for the erased range:

```
  iterator erase(const_iterator _First, const_iterator _Last)
  {
     const size_type _Offset = _First - cbegin();
     const size_type _LastOffset = _Last - cbegin();

     iterator _NewEnd = std::move(begin() + _LastOffset, end(), begin() + _Offset);
     _DestroyData(_NewEnd, end());
     _SetSize(_NewEnd - begin());

     return begin() + _Offset;
  }
```

Comment: erm, [underscores followed by capital letters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/819272)? Did you literally copy this from an STL implementation?